# Doubts with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make some code that sends a form that first makes sure if it is filled correctly. When I click on the "enviar formulario" button, it doesn't call the javascript code and does not do anything.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      if(document.getElementById("nombre").value.length() < 2){
        alert("Error");
        return 1;
      }
      else if(!document.getElementById("edad").value.isInteger()){
        alert("Error");
        return 1;
      }

      else if(!document.getElementById("email").value.includes("@")){
        alert("Error");
        return 1;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
      }
    }
</script>
</head>

 <body>
    <form id="formulario"action = "https://postman-echo.com/get" 
      method = GET type=text>
     Nombre:&nbsp;  <input id="nombre" type="text"/>
     <br><br>
     Edad:&nbsp;    <input id="edad" type="text"/>
     <br><br>
     E-mail:&nbsp;  <input id="email" type="text"/>
    </form>

<button onclick= "test()">Enviar formulario</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see an `"enviar formulario"` button anywhere...

Comment: ups, I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like `document.getElementById("nombre").length()`

If you are trying to read the length of  input text do this

```
document.getElementById("nombre").value.length
```

**EDIT 1:**

There is no method as isInteger(). So use parseInt() instead

This will be your working code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      if(document.getElementById("nombre").value.length < 2){
        alert("Error");
        return 1;
      }
      else if(!parseInt(document.getElementById("edad").value)){
        alert("Error");
        return 1;
      }

      else if(!document.getElementById("email").value.includes("@")){
        alert("Error");
        return 1;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
      }
    }
</script>
</head>

 <body>
    <form id="formulario"action = "https://postman-echo.com/get" 
      method = GET type=text>
     Nombre:&nbsp;  <input id="nombre" type="text"/>
     <br><br>
     Edad:&nbsp;    <input id="edad" type="text"/>
     <br><br>
     E-mail:&nbsp;  <input id="email" type="text"/>
    </form>

<button onclick= "test()">Enviar formulario</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand my errors now but I thought that I could use that method :/ https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isinteger.asp

Comment: You can use that too but in this way . Syntax is like this Number.isInteger(value)  Value is mandatory

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the length of the whole input tag rather than the text in it.

```
if (document.getElementById("nombre").value.length < 2)
{
    ...
}
if (!document.getElementById("edad").value.isInteger())
{
    ...
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Alright, I've changed that. But the button is not working anyways

Comment: I click the button and nothing happens. Maybe the button is not calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

First, please check if your control is reaching the test method, use a debugger (I prefer chrome)

After that check your syntax in the console, while the code is at the breakpoint

You can share your findings here

Comment: It's my first time with JS and the debugger so I'm not sure If I'm using it well but it says that isInteger() is not a function and the some goes for lenght()